# Bounding entropy difference using relative entropy

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Can one directly bound the entropy difference $|H(p) - H(q)|$ for distributions $p$ and $q$ using the relative entropy $D(p||q)$, without first going through the Pinsker's inequality and using the continuity bound for entropy?

This is interesting to me because both of these seem to be "natural" quantities in information theory and it is not clear to me that one needs to go through one-norm to prove bounds on $|H(p) - H(q)|$. If one cannot create a (much) better bound directly using $D(p||q)$, I'd like to understand why.

Comment: Just a try! Always $\sum_i p_i\log \frac{1}{q_i} = H(p)+D(p\|q)$. Therefore, if it is the case that 'information is maximum when weighted by the true distribution', then $\sum_i p_i\log \frac{1}{q_i}\le \sum_i q_i\log \frac{1}{q_i} = H(q)$. Hence $D(p\|q)\le H(q)-H(p)$.

Comment: @Ashok is that known to be true-  'if it is the case that 'information is maximum when weighted by the true distribution'?

Comment: That's what I'm not sure! :) Heard of it somewhere; not sure.

Comment: Looks the statement 'information is maximum when weighted by the true distribution' is not true. Looks $\sum_i p_i\log \frac{1}{q_i}$ is maximum when $p$ is degenerate.

Comment: Mmm, I think that you need to use entropy continuity (maybe Pinsker maybe other similar bound). Because entropy is an expectation and KL brings expectation closer as $D(p\|q)=\sup_X\mathbb{E}_p[X]-\log\mathbb{E}_q[e^X]$

Comment: I also cannot think of anything else. If possible choose $p$ absolutely continuous to $q$, if both options work, choose them such that the bound is minimal. Let $p_-=\min_xp(x)$.
Then we have $|H(p)-H(q)|\le -2\ln(p_-)d_{tv}(p,q)+D(q\|p)\le-\ln(p_-)\sqrt{2D(q\|p)}+D(q\|p)$, where we could also take $D(p\|q)$ under the square root.